# 12.04 Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

I have ASUS UL50Vt with nvidia optimus hybrid graphics (GeForce 210M).
I recently installed ubuntu 12.04, and in Details app it was showing me, that I am on Intel video driver.
So, I installed bumblebee and after reboot, Details showed "VESA: GT218 Board - 0698a740"
As VESA differs from NVIDIA, I uninstalled bumblebee, but bug hasn't gone :(

Now my Xorg.0.log contains:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep nvidia
[    12.616] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.634] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    12.634] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.634] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    12.634] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    12.634] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    12.634] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.634] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    12.634] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.634] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    12.634] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

Additional drivers says, that NVIDIA is activated but not currently in use:

```
jockey-text --list | grep nvidia
kmod:nvidia_current - nvidia_current (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_current_updates - nvidia_current_updates (Proprietary, Enabled, Not in     use)
kmod:nvidia_experimental_304 - Experimental NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_experimental_310 - Experimental NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
```

NVIDIA X Server Settings writes on start:

You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.

Suggested by https://askubuntu.com/a/121612/165811

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
```

does not change anything. I'm still on fallback VESA driver. Resolution is 1280x768 instead of 1366x768.

How can I find out why nvidia-current fails to load nvidia module, which, I believe exists:

```
modprobe -l | grep nvidia
kernel/drivers/video/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/nvidia/forcedeth.ko
updates/dkms/nvidia_current.ko
updates/dkms/nvidia_current_updates.ko
updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
```

If it can help, here is my xorg.conf:

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.88  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Wed Mar 27 15:32:58 PDT 2013


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Also, how can switch to my on-board Intel graphics, that served me well earlier?

*UPDATE*

lshw shows me, that my display is UNCLAIMED:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GT218 [GeForce G210M]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: a2
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:f0000000-f007ffff
```

It looks like linux does not know about my integrated graphics at all:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210M] (rev a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you uninstall the nvidia driver and make sure you are running on the intel driver.
After this, follow the instructions from the wiki:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Please report any specific problems you may encounter when running things exactly as specified in the guide.

Good luck!

Comment: Can someone update the guide for Ubuntu18.04 Bionic Beaver? It doesn't seem to work anymore.